# Why the config from toro php router in .htaccess doesn't work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, router

the [Toro docs](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP/) show:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

but i tryed many times and different ways, but, doesn't work... After a lot of searching i found this ([source](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP/issues/51)):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Just need to change in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`  the **`/`** to **`?`** , to get this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]`

Someone know why the original doesn't work, or have a different aproach for this?

**MORE INFO**
Host: php5.4 fastcgi, shared host, company Dreamhost.
Just accept SCRIPT_NAME instead of PATH_INFO

the Toro code that handle it is:

```
$path_info = '/';
        if (!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
            $path_info = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
        }
        else if (!empty($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] !== '/index.php') {
            $path_info = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
        }
        else {
            if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
         $path_info = (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') > 0) ? strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?', true) : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are running on a server that doesn't support the PATH_INFO style of cgi. This is where the script itself is `/index.php` and the "PATH_INFO" is the pathname that comes after it. Take a look at the [AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) documentation:

> This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the `PATH_INFO` environment variable.
>
> For example, assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that contains only the single file `here.html`. Then requests for `/test/here.html/more` and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as `PATH_INFO`.
>
> The primary purpose of the `AcceptPathInfo` directive is to allow you to override the handler's choice of accepting or rejecting `PATH_INFO`. This override is required, for example, when you use a filter, such as `INCLUDES`, to generate content based on `PATH_INFO`. The core handler would usually reject the request, so you can use the following configuration to enable such a script:

```
<Files "mypaths.shtml">
Options +Includes
SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

So you could try turning `AcceptPathInfo` to "On" and see if that helps.

Comment: I got more information and my host do not accept `PATH_INFO`, just `SCRIPT_NAME`, but i still need to use `?` instead `/` . I saw this article http://www.infopotato.com/blog/index/path_info this clarify more my questions too. Thanks for the response, this started to make me understand what is happening. I tryed to solve but no success, and because the things is working, I stop to try change. Yes the server is PHP 5.4 fastcgi and is sharedhost on Dreamhost.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about mapping URLs to paths to scripts that generate response.

Apache gets HTTP request, which contains a URL, specifically the [path and query string part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax) of it. Mod_rewrite rewrites the URL using rules from the server configuration (multiple files: apache2.conf, httpd.conf, virtual host configs, .htaccess, …). Then Apache splits it in the first question mark and interprets the path part as a filesystem path (with DocumentRoot prepended). If the file does not exist, 404 Not Found response is usually generated. If it is an image or a HTML document, it is sent as is. If it is a script, it is executed and somehow gets query string and other info from the request.

I cannot be very specific, because Apache is very modular and configurable. Especially script execution is quite a complicated topic. The general part of Apache's work is request parsing → URL to filesystem path mapping → response generation.

URLs visible to clients can contain no question marks at all and still a script can be executed and be given some extra info from the URL. One way to do this is URL rewriting using mod_rewrite and .htaccess, where */* is rewritten to *?*. As Jon Lin already wrote, AcceptPathInfo is another option. I am not sure if any of them is clearly better or worse for your needs. When used on a large server, performance is likely to be an issue, but that's not your case.